# Task Queue completion callback

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, task-queue

I am using google cloud task queue to do some long running tasks.
Once all the task have been completed i wanted to send some notification.

I am using below code to get number of pending task in my thread

QueueStatistics stats= taskQueue.fetchStatistics();
    stats.getNumTasks();

but here i am continuously checking value return by getNumTask() method.
If it is zero then i notify others.
Is there any callback available which could notify me once all the task of my queue have been completed.

Regards,

Comment: Call back to? A task can send an e-mail message or use a channel to send messages.

Answer (score 0):

If concurrently running tasks is not a must for your application, you can setup the queue with max-concurrent-requests set to 1, so that tasks will run one by one:

```
<queue-entries>
  <queue>
    <name>my-queue</name>
    <rate>1/s</rate>
    <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
  </queue>
</queue-entries>
```

Then, after push all tasks in the queue, you push a notification task to the same queue. The notification task will be the last one on the queue and will be executed after all tasks are completed.

Notes: be careful with auto retries when one of your tasks fails. This will make the notification task not the last one on queue. Maybe you can purge the queue on failure then retry.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of using Tasks in most of the cases, which is making use of concurrency to complete a large job.